# Prettify response output

Tags: php, api

I cobbled together some code to retrieve info using Yelp API.

```html
$postData = "grant_type=client_credentials&".
    "client_id=MyClientIDl94gqHAg&".
    "client_secret=SomEcoDehIW09e6BGuBi4NlJ43HnnHl4S7W5eoXUkB";


// GET TOKEN
$curl = curl_init();

//set the url
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.yelp.com/oauth2/token");
//tell curl we are doing a post
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
//set post fields
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
//tell curl we want the returned data
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($curl);

if($result){
    $data = json_decode($result);
}

// GET RESTAURANT INFO
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/north-india-restaurant-san-francisco",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "authorization: Bearer ".$data->access_token
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

//close connection
curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
```

It works fine, however the output seems to be in a single row. I've tried wrapping it with `<pre></pre>` but got it in a single row... How do I format this output for easier comprehension?

Comment: you can do a json_decode and json_encode with `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`. But do that only for developing purposes!!

Comment: @Jeff, yes, I just need to display the output as a formatted block of code. So when I tried: echo json_decode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); my screen shows a single word: Array. However, when I try echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); I get extra back slash in front of each double quote..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode and encode with JSON_PRETTY_PRINT the received json:

```
$a='{"error": {"code": "TOKEN_MISSING", "description": "An access token must be supplied in order to use this endpoint."}}';
$b=json_decode($a);
$c=json_encode($b, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo "<pre>".$c."</pre>";

// result:

{   
    "error": {   
        "code": "TOKEN_MISSING",
        "description": "An access token must be supplied in order to use this endpoint."
    }
}
```

Note, that [JSON_PRETTY_PRINT](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) is not available in php < 5.4.0

Comment: Works great, thanks.